# Botão só pode ser clicado após 24 horas depois do clique

Tags: php, mysql

Olá pessoal eu tenho um site e quero o seguintes ( Não consigo fazer, nem achei na net ), Um botão que após o click é registrado na db, após isso o botão só pode ser clicado após 24 horas, a tabela do check-in é assim:

```
-- Check-in Table
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `checkin` (
-- AUTO INCREMENT... ID DO CLICK
`id_click` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
-- Username do usuario isso você não precisa add um formulario pra pegar o nome < ja tenho >
`nome` varchar(64) NOT NULL ,
`hora` int(64) NOT NULL,
-- Não sei se isso é o suficiente
PRIMARY KEY (`id_click`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=529 ;
```

EX: eu clicko no botão inserta na db, e após 24 horas o botão libera novamente  e assim por diante

(NOME PODE COLOCAR PARA INSERTAR QUALQUER UM ex: Alfonso, DPS EU CRIO UM FORM)

Comment: Está mal formulada essa sua pergunta. Depois que o botão é clicado e insere no db, o botão fica indisponível por 24 horas para todos os usuários?

Comment: Não apenas para o usuário que clicou no botão

Comment: Nesse caso tem que ser uma pagina de login (para caracterizar que seja único) com mais uma condição na clausula where, ou seja, onde a diferença entre a ultima data registrada e a data atual seja maior que 24 horas. Se essas condições forem satisfeitas libera o botão pra ser clicável.

Comment: Se alguma resposta solucionou seu problema marque-a como aceita. Veja como em https://i.stack.imgur.com/evLUR.png e veja porque em https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta/1079#1079

Comment: Esse jogo é muito complicado pra mim, rsrsrs, mas de qualquer forma tem que fazer login para entrar, é ai que vai reconhecer e desativar o botão

Comment: Não consegui ver o tal do botão, talvez usem cookies criados quando você faz login

Comment: Eu já tenho o sistema de login, senha , registro, sessão cookie minha dB pesa uns 5MB só preciso deste maldito botão que só o dono no Yuup tem (eu conheço ele mais ele n passa nada) ele diz que é fácil fazer só que no site dele ele trocou o botão por um inserto quando entra no client.php pra ser mais fácil prós users mais antes disse era um botão que ficava na /me.php

Comment: Um cara do ramo também fez mais ele perdeu do mega dele é tá sem tempo pra fazer pois ele tem outros projetos...

Comment: tem como dar insert em todos os users da db sem entrar no site tipo sem eu entrar no site ele add auto

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ao invés de usar um campo “hora” do tipo `int` mude para o tipo `datetime` e coloque o valor `default` `NOW()`:

`ALTER TABLE checkin CHANGE hora DATETIME default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`

dessa forma você não precisa inserir a hora do registro, ela será inserida automaticamente com a hora do servidor.

antes de fazer um novo insert:

`SELECT hora FROM checkin WHERE hora > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)`

se o select trouxer registros não libera o insert

Comment: Não respondido a questão

Comment: ué, não é para inserir o registro apenas se ja passou 24h apos o ultimo chekin? não tem muito segredo, você só vai precisar completar com os dados do usuario em questão `WHERE nome = ‘algumacoisa’`

Answer (score 2):

Crie uma tabela que contenha as colunas, por exemplo,  `nome` e `senha` para caracterizar que o usuário seja único e que contenha também uma coluna `data` do tipo `DATETIME`

> Faça um SELECT e verifique se há registro, se houver desabilite o botão.

### Veja a seguir um exemplo com mysqli

**PHP**

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "USUARIO";
$password = "SENHA";
$dbname = "NOME_DB";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if (!$conn) {
    die("Conexão falhou: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$result = $conn->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM checkin WHERE nome='$nome' AND senha='$senha' AND data > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)");

$row = $result->fetch_row();
if ($row[0] > 0) {
        //vai desabilitar o botão
       $disabled = "disabled";
} else {
        /****** Verifique se o usuário existe ******/
        $result = $conn->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM checkin WHERE nome='$nome' AND senha='$senha'");
        $row = $result->fetch_row();
        if ($row[0] > 0) {
             /****** Se existir faz UPDATE na data com data atual *****/
             $conn->query("UPDATE checkin SET data=now() WHERE nome='$nome' AND senha='$senha'");
        }else{
            /****** se NÃO existir faz o INSERT ********/
            $conn->query("INSERT INTO checkin (nome, senha, data) VALUES ('$nome', '$senha', now())");

        }
}
```

**HTML**

```
..............
..............
<button type="button" <?php echo $disabled ?>>Click Me!</button>
..............
```

Comment: não e assim, não precisa do login etc isso eu já tenho pode deixar só o nome mesmo, vamos supor: eu já fiz o login dai da dashboard tem um botão Que quando clicado só pode ser clicado denovo apos 24 horas,  não precisa de verificar se o user exite mais verificar se o botão já foi clicado nas ultimas 24 horas

Comment: @Alaskah, da forma que eu entendi que você quer acho que nem Deus é capaz de fazer.  Mas o caminho passa pela minha resposta e a do @ Hebert de Lima, veja se consegue adaptar a suas necessidades.

Comment: Claro que é possivel, tem nesse site: http://yuup.online/trocas lo lado esquerdo tem o nome picoles, ali mostra como funciona, agora funciona quando você entra no jogo, mais antes erá em um botão eu quero fazer nesse modo em botão OBS: o logando que fala é entrar no jogo